# Newly added button( DevExpress.XtraBars.ButtonItem) display as disable .Why so that?

Tags: devexpress

i have added a button item to a `top ribbon`too my windows form . but it shown like disable (couldn't perform click event) when i run the application.but in the Button properties Enable =true.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygW1e.png)

Comment: Could you clarify what is meant by a "reborn controller" ?

Comment: actually it should be ribbon controller. please see attached image??

Comment: WPF? WinForms? ASP.NET? And properties being changed at runtime? Are you restoring any previous Ribbon layout?

Comment: Best practice is to correct your original post so that other contributors can see the it without needing to drop down here into the comments. I did that for you today. You'll be more likely to get help with a more clear and complete original question.

Comment: okay jeff thank you. i'm quite new for this